# How do I create a group calendar in owncloud?

Tags: calendar, owncloud

I'm using Owncloud 8 (hosted by blaucloud.de) and I can create multiple users, each with multiple calendars. How do I create a shared calendar?

Their [web site](https://owncloud.org/features/) says:

> Share your calendar with other ownCloud users or groups on your ownCloud server, easy and quick.

That's exactly what I want.

There is a [pontential duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/593424/owncloud-multiple-users-in-one-calendar?rq=1), however, the answer does not apply since the dialog they mention in not shown in Owncloud 8.

Comment: Have you looked in the documentation on their site or contacted ownCloud for support?

Comment: @CharlieRB There is no such information in [user manual](https://owncloud.org/blog/owncloud-server-8-0-for-users/) and I'm not sure they offer support for end users.

Comment: If their site claims it, they should be willing to explain how. I'd send them an email. Also, look through their forum, specifically [this post](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=26816&p=81086&hilit=share+calendar#p81086). It appears you are not the only one who can not share calendars.

Answer (score 1):

Owncloud 8 supports this. However, there appears to be an UI bug with some versions of Firefox that hides the 'Share' icon. If you have the same problem, try a different browser. Chromium worked for me.